# Connect to grafana loki

Tags: go, grafana-loki

For a project, I would like to create a program in go which fetch the logs stored by loki. I have all the labels needed but I don't know where to start. It would be great if someone has a manual, a doc or a little example which could help me start my project.

Comment: Maybe look at the logcli tool that comes with loki. It's written in go https://github.com/grafana/loki/blob/main/cmd/logcli/.

Comment: Yes I'trying to understand this repo but it's a bit hard because of all the argument management next to the loki part. So I decided to work on this repo and ask if someone already dev something like that

Comment: @LarsChristianJensen I found a great doc which will help me. https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/api/ thanks for your help